What does $\sum$ mean of vector spaces (e.g. as used by Artin)?
What does $\sum$ mean of vector spaces (e.g. as used by Artin)?  For example, Artin writes:

$5.3$: Let $W_1,\cdots,W_k$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$, such that $V = \sum W_i$. Assume that $W_1 \cap W_2 = 0$, $(W_1+W_2) \cap W_3 = 0$, ..., $(W_1+W_2+\cdots+W_{k-1}) \cap W_k = 0$. Prove that $V$ is the direct sum of the subspaces $W_1,\cdots,W_k$.

What does $$V = \sum W_i$$ mean?  It can't mean direct sum, because that is what the question asks you to prove.

It just means the sum of spaces (not necessarily direct). We could write, for instance, $\sum_{i=1}^n W_i$ as a shorthand for $W_1 + W_2 + W_3 + \cdots + W_n$, where
$$
W_1 + W_2 := \{ w_1 + w_2 \mid w_1 \in W_1, w_2 \in W_2 \}
$$
(By omitting the bound as in $V = \sum W_i$, we are just lazily assuming that the bounds can be understood from context, same as people often do with ordinary summation.)
